# How to know whether an Update/Insert/Delete has taken place on a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table called Table A and I have created a trigger that handles INSERTS, UPDATES, DELETES. Now in order to process my next steps, I want to know what DML action has taken place. How do I know whether an Update/Insert/Delete has taken place.

Your thoughts, feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: Or you create one trigger for every event

Comment: That's a possible solution. I was wondering if there is a place where we can do it all at once. What is the best practice ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the trigger, you have two special tables at your disposal: `INSERTED` and `DELETED`. If a row exists only in the `INSERTED` table, then an INSERT operation occurred. Likewise, if a row exists only in the `DELETED` table, then a DELETE operation occurred. If the row exists in both tables, then an UPDATE occurred and the `INSERTED` table holds the new values while the `DELETED` table holds the old values.

INSERTed Rows:

```
SELECT i.*
    FROM INSERTED i
        LEFT JOIN DELETED d
            ON i.PrimaryKey = d.PrimaryKey
    WHERE d.PrimaryKey IS NULL
```

DELETEd Rows:

```
SELECT d.*
    FROM DELETED d
        LEFT JOIN INSERTED i
            ON d.PrimaryKey = i.PrimaryKey
    WHERE i.PrimaryKey IS NULL
```

UPDATEd Rows:

```
SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED i
        INNER JOIN DELETED d
            ON i.PrimaryKey = d.PrimaryKey
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for your answer. But when I try to compile my trigger I get an error message, invalid column PrimaryKey

Comment: @SaiBand: `PrimaryKey` was a made up column name for the purposes of my example. You'd need to substitute the name of the real primary key column(s) from your table.

Comment: Thanks! that works after replacing the primary key with the actual one in the table. Cheers!